# how to join different functions created in different ways without generating a typing error

Tags: haskell

basically i need to unite all these functions that change my initial tuple and print it, but it is giving an indentation error, i never did something like this before and i did not find the answer in the book i use for haskell

```
generItemPosition :: [([Char], Int)] -> [([Char], Int, Int)]
generItemPosition = zipWith (\ z (x, y) -> (x, y, z)) [1 ..]

sortListForPriority :: [([Char], Int, Int)] -> [([Char], Int, Int)]
sortListForPriority [] = []
sortListForPriority (x: xs) = sortListForPriority smaller ++ [x] ++ sortListForPriority larger
  where
    smaller = filter (\ y -> focus y <= focus x) xs
    larger = filter (\ y -> focus y> focus x) xs
    focus (_, x, _) = x

updatePriority :: [([Char], Int, Int)] -> [([Char], Int, Int)]
updatePriority = zipWith (\ y (x, _, z) -> (x, y, z)) [1 ..]

orderListByOrder :: [([Char], Int, Int)] -> [([Char], Int, Int)]
orderListByOrder [] = []
orderListByOrder (x: xs) = orderListByOrder smaller ++ [x] ++ orderListByOrder larger
  where
    smaller = filter (\ y -> focus y <= focus x) xs
    larger = filter (\ y -> focus y> focus x) xs
    focus (_, _, x) = x

printUpdatedList :: [([Char], Int)] -> [([Char], Int, Int)]
printUpdatedList xs = orderListByOrder (updatePriority (sortListForPriority(generItemPosition)))
```

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: btw: you almost had it - you just missed the `xs` inside the innermost `(..)`

Comment: edits must not. invalidate. the. answers.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to chain those functions - that's what the `.` operator (function composition) is for:

```hs
printUpdatedList :: [([Char], Int)] -> [([Char], Int, Int)]
printUpdatedList = 
   orderListByOrder . updatePriority . sortListForPriority .generItemPosition
```

will type-check and I think you want this

I'm pretty sure that you'll find some explanation to `.` in whatever learning resource you are using - it's pretty all over the place in Haskell

it's type is: `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` and it's one of the main ways to chain together functions.

---

note that I used a *point-free* style again - if you want your `xs` back it looks a bit different:

```hs
printUpdatedList xs = 
   orderListByOrder . updatePriority . sortListForPriority $ generItemPosition xs
```

there are several ways to do this:

```hs
printUpdatedList xs = 
   orderListByOrder . updatePriority $ sortListForPriority $ generItemPosition xs
```

...

```hs
printUpdatedList xs = 
   orderListByOrder $ updatePriority $ sortListForPriority $ generItemPosition xs
```

it's all the same as

```hs
printUpdatedList xs = 
   orderListByOrder ( updatePriority ( sortListForPriority (generItemPosition xs) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

printedUpdateList must be either specified pointfree:

```hs
printUpdatedList = 
   orderListByOrder . 
   updatePriority . 
   sortListForPriority .
   generItemPosition
```

or ensure you pass the argument:

```hs
printUpdatedList xs = 
   orderListByOrder (
     updatePriority (
       sortListForPriority( 
         generItemPosition xs)))
```

If you want to print the result, look into `Debug.Trace` or you will have to use IO monads, e.g (untested):

```
printUpdatedList xs = do
  let result = print_ xs
  putStrLn (show result)
  where print_ = orderListByOrder .updatePriority . sortListForPriority . generItemPosition
```

Comment: the last part with IO seems off if you `result <- ... ` it'll somewhat indicate the list-monad (the result of your `print_`) but of course `putStrLn` will be `IO` - also you missed `xs` on the left of the `=`

Comment: Your last one can be as simple as `printUpdatedList = print . orderListByOrder . {- ... -}`.